# Creating an OS X PKG file on Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, archiving

I have Debian / Ubuntu / Xubuntu. I'm trying to distribute and run a Python file with the least number of clicks for the end user.  How do I create a PKG file for Mac OS X on Linux?

Edit:

I think I may have ended up using a rar or a zip file, which has contents that can be ran somewhat like a DMG can be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323818/packagemaker-for-creating-mac-packages-on-windows-linux this SE question might be a start, also http://www.osxgnu.org/info/osxpackages.html - other than some files that are generated by packagemaker, it looks like the pkg file is a fairly standard nix style compressed archive

Comment: If I extract the contents of a .pkg file, there's some directories, and a PAX file (which i can make), and a BOM file, (which i've no idea how to make on a platform other than osx)

Comment: @TomO'Connor Is your problem identical to Luke's, i.e. you have a script file and just want to execute it (and could accept alternatives), or do you actually want to create a proper Installer `.pkg`, possibly containing lots of files?

Comment: Initially, the problem's identical, but there's more than just one file we want/need to package up.

Comment: @TomO'Connor It's much easier to create Mac OS X application bundles.  There might be easier options that integrate just as well with your target system (i.e. easy for your users). Consider specifying your requirements in more detail. If they're not too fancy, and more along the lines of *running* instead of *installing*, this might work quite well.

Answer (score 5):

Some multiplatform installers I know of are :

[**IzPack**](http://izpack.org/) is a an open source software installer generator. As it uses Java you need the JRE on the target platform.

The free [**InstallJammer**](http://www.installjammer.com/) is :

> a multiplatform GUI installer and builder designed to be
>   completely cross-platform and function on Windows and most all
>   versions of UNIX with **eventual** support for Mac OS X.

You could contact the developer, as he is very responsive.

[**InstallAnywhere**](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm) is a commercial multiplatform installer. Its Standard Edition is priced at $1,999.

BitRock's [**InstallBuilder**](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/) (don't look at the [price tag](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/purchase.html)) also claims :

> Generate installers for all target platforms from a single project
>   file. Create all your installers from a single build environment!

[**JExpress**](http://www.denova.com/) is another one at only $849.

The only one from the above that I have used is InstallJammer, which I really recommend. If OS X is already available in beta, don't hesitate to try it, as the developer corrects bugs at a very fast pace.

Comment: Interesting, but not seeming to answer the exact question, not from my POV, anyway.

Comment: Then what is your POV?

Comment: Well, free would be a starting point, and the only free one is IzPack.  which doesn't make DMG/PKG files, but is actually it's own installer format.  Like we need another one of those(!).

Comment: IzPack and InstallJammer are open source, so you could have a look at how it is done if you want to roll your own.

Comment: Another idea would be to use a trial version of one of the commercial packages to create the installation, then use it as a model for repackaging on Linux. I don't know if Lion pkg files are still [xarchives](http://code.google.com/p/xar/) or are now standard zip files. (One nasty idea is to install the trial in a disposable VM.)

Comment: Mac OS X no longer comes with Java out of the box, so IzPack has quite a big requirement for running a single script...

Comment: As above, if the installation has always the same files and folders and actions, just the content of the files being different, then you can create the pkg by one of the above products (java is to be avoided in this case), examine the structure of the resulting pkg file using xar or zip or whatever, and write a script that creates such a pkg from given user files. You will be using from now on only your own script, so that the above commercial product will be used only once as a one-time tool to generate the template pkg for you.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry - it will not work.

Linux may create Solaris and BSD pkg files which are tarballs with some metadata, which will lead all your searches to a complete no-go.

Comment: I don't believe you.

Comment: Make a DMG file in Linux or Windows - OSX PKG is same format...

Comment: That's totally wrong.